# syntax error in using SECRET_KEY in __init__py in django

Tags: django, syntax-error, secret-key

I have read that it is not secure to store the `SECRET_KEY` in `settings.py` as its default. So, I decided to store it in my `__init__.py`.
I wrote in `__init__.py` which is beside `settings.py`:

```
export SECRET_KEY= 'hf7^vrmc!^agnpba#^+$9ac-@eullgd-=ckq&u1zu$b7nqc)%_'
```

This is the only line in my `__init__.py`. Then in `settings.py` I changed the line

```
SECRET_KEY = 'hf7^vrmc!^agnpba#^+$9ac-@eullgd-=ckq&u1zu$b7nqc)%_'
```

into

```
SECRET_KEY = get_env_variable('SECRET_KEY')
```

but when I try to runserver, I receive Syntax error as below:

```
…
__init__.py", line 1
    export SECRET_KEY= 'hf7^vrmc!^agnpba#^+$9ac-@eullgd-=ckq&u1zu$b7nqc)%_'
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What's wrong here? 
Thank you in advanced.

---

I have edited my code as bellow with the help of comments here, but still no succeed:

I have
 `SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')` in `settings.py`, and `export SECRET_KEY='hf7^vrmc!^agnpba#^+$9ac-@eullgd-=ckq&u1zu$b7nqc)%_'` in `.bash_profile` . These gives me the error of

```
  3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 126, in init raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.") django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty
```

When I copy the file .`bash_profile` from the `home/mydirectory` and paste it beside `manage.py` of the project, there is no error in the result of writing `python manage.py runserver` in terminal. (The above error was in terminal with exactly this command). 
But, When I `startproject` from `cPanel` and test my website on the browser, I receive the error of `There is something wrong` and my website does not work.
I guess something like this is happens: When I press `startproject` from cPanel, it starts from the outer root, so it sees that I have two instances of `.bash_profile`. However, when I go to project root from the terminal and write `python manage.py runserver` it just sees that specific `.bash_profile` inside the project folder. Is it correct? If so, how can I solve my problem to have a secure `SECRET_KEY` with available website?

If I delete the inner `.bash_profile` and change `BASE_DIR` to `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))` (as here [link](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/create-a-blank-django-project/)), I will have no error in `terminal` by `python manage.py runserver`. It results:

`System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 24, 2020 - 21:04:33
Django version 2.1, using settings 'myprojectt.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.`

and it won't give the error of `SECRET_KEY` can't be empty. But when I press `startproject` from `cPanel` and go to my domain from the browser, I receive

```
`We're sorry, but something went wrong.`
```

Note: my website works properly if I explicitly write `SECRET_KEY` in `settings.py`, **BUT without any security**

Comment: Put the export in your bash profile instead...see instructions here https://medium.com/@ksarthak4ever/hiding-passwords-and-secret-keys-in-environment-variables-ccca72a3b01e

Comment: @ Jim: Thanks, your solution worked. Now I have the error of __NameError: name 'get_env_variable' is not defined__  in settings.py for the line __SECRET_KEY = get_env_variable('SECRET_KEY')__. Should I define it myself as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623443/secret-key-errors-with-environment-variables) or should I import any library for it?

Comment: check the link I sent you, it shows you exactly how to set up both the bash profile piece and how to retrieve in settings.py - just follow the guide

Comment: I did it as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623443/secret-key-errors-with-environment-variables
) but know I have the error:
 /3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 126, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

Comment: @Jim: Thank you. I did what it based on the link you wrote. Again I have the error of 

3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 126, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Comment: You're using `SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')` in settings.py and getting that error?

Comment: @Jim: Yes. I have 'SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')' in settings.py, and export SECRET_KEY= 'hf7^vrmc!^agnpba#^+$9ac-@eullgd-=ckq&u1zu$b7nqc)%_' in .bash_profile and this gives me the error of The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty. But surprisingly when I copy the file .bash_profile from the home/mydirectory and paste it beside my manage.py there is no error!(All of these jobs are done in cpanel)

Comment: @Jim:  I guess there is a problem with my BASE_DIR which is BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), but I don't know how to resolve it, I googled my error a lot with no success.

Comment: @Jim Is it ok to have a copy of .bash_profile file beside manage.py? Is it secure? And can this duplication make any problem to the performance of program?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that by copying `.bash_profile` beside `manage.py`, only the errors gone when I runserver from the terminal. But when I startproject from the cPanel, my domain does not work and gives the error of there is something wrong (even when debug= True)
So, even copying that file won't solve my problem.
* If I write the SECTER_KEY explicitly in settings.py everything works well and my website appears. BUT without any security

Comment: What operating system/distribution are you running your Django application on?

Comment: @Jim: It is on a server of Cloud Linux centos 7

Answer (score 0):

```
import os   
os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

Requested explanation:
os is default module to interact with operative system.
os.environ is a dictionary with environment variables and get.('SECRET_KEY') method to get value wich key is 'SECRET_KEY' . 
Summary, you get value from environment variable called 'SECRET_KEY'

If you are using os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') should be because you PREVIOUSLY have set an environment variable called 'SECRET_KEY'. How did I set a variable?

maybe:

bash:

export SECRET_KEY=abcdfghijklm

or maybe:

dos:

SET SECRET_KEY=abcdfghijklm

or maybe your editor/framework has a setting option to set environments variable.

P.D. WITHOUT "" or '' to set enviroments variables

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: os is default module to interact with operative system, os.environ is a dictionary with environment variables and get.('SECRET_KEY') method to get value wich key is 'SECRET_KEY' .  Summary, you get value from environment variable called 'SECRET_KEY'

Comment: @bertinhogago Could you please read my comment for Jim above?
 my problem after using os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') is as below:
 I have 'SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')' in settings.py, and export SECRET_KEY= 'hf7^vrmc!^agnpba#^+$9ac-@eullgd-=ckq&u1zu$b7nqc)%_' in .bash_profile and this gives me the error of The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty. But surprisingly when I copy the file .bash_profile from the home/mydirectory and paste it beside my manage.py there is no error!(All of these jobs are done in cpanel) Although copying this file beside manage.py may not be secure, yes?

Comment: @bertinhogago So I need a way to know in which part of setting.py it is defined for os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') to search only inside this project folder, and then I need to know how to tell it to find .bash_profile in home/myname directory.

Albeit, If defining the path to that directory not problematic for security.

Comment: @bertinhogago please add all explanation **to your answer by editing it**

Answer (score 0):

You can leave out the 'export':

```
SECRET_KEY= 'hf7^vrmc!^agnpba#^+$9ac-@eullgd-=ckq&u1zu$b7nqc)%_'
```

Comment: please see the comment for the question of someone of  Patrick Haugh here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623443/secret-key-errors-with-environment-variables). He mentioned that _did you use SECRET_KEY=password or export SECRET_KEY=password ? Only the second will allows subprocesses to see the variable_

Answer (score 0):

Having secret keys in the ***any*** of the source code files is problematic.

We normally store our environment variables in the same directory as the settings file in an .env file which is not committed to the git repository via an entries in .gitignore.

extract of .gitignore for .env files and env

```
.env*
```

We include `python-dotenv` in the requirements.txt file to load the .env file.

and we load the environment variables in the .env file in the settings.py file.

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

#print('Loading environment')
#print(__file__)
env_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'.env')
#print(env_path)
load_dotenv(verbose=True,dotenv_path=env_path)
```

Comment: Could you please explain it? Should I make an empty page and save it as some_name.env? or it exist somewhere? In my cPanel, the only file I have with "env" included is : /virtualenv/myprojectt/3.7/bin/set_env_vars.py which is .py not .env
And I have the same question for _requirement.txt_

Comment: **important** Another question is that, you said: _Having secret keys in the any of the source code files is problematic._
Does it mean that my source codes are accessible? Does this accessibility made after putting SECRET_KEY there? Or it can happen always?
It is important for me that visitors not be able to receive my backend code. So, I put all my backend codes outside of public_html folder. Is it enough for security of my backend sourcecode?

Comment: Having secret keys in your source code means ***anyone*** with access to your source code repository will see those keys. 
We use .gitignore to make sure the .env file is not put into the repository. We have requirements.txt in the root of the project. We have .env in the same folder as settings.py. We put the .env file up on the server.